# Python Error Import Class another directory

Tags: python

I have structure project python

```
MyProject
+Classes
    -stage_competition.py
main.py
```

Executing Python (main.py) - Show error "ModuleNotFoundError("No module named 'Classes'",)"

I tried import direct, but is not working too, always showing same error

```
from Classes.stage_competition import Stage_competition

item = Stage_competition("field1", "field2", "field3" , "field4")


Create class Stage_competition

class Stage_competition(object):
    """description of class"""

    def __init__(self, type_competition, datalake, competition ,hour):
        self.type_competition = type_competition
        self.datalake = datalake
        self.competition = competition
        self.hour = hour

    def settype_competition(self, type_competition):
        self.type_competition = type_competition

    def setdatalake(self, datalake):
        self.datalake = datalake

    def getcompetition(self):
        return self.competition

    def gethour(self):
        return self.hour
```

Comment: Which python version are you using?

Comment: version Python 3.7

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If the `Classes` is in the same folder as `main.py`, you should import it this way (notice the dot before Classes):

```
from .Classes.stage_competition import Stage_competition
```

Alternatively, you could add directory to `Classes` to `PYTHONPATH`, which allows you to `import Classes` from anywhere.

Comment: main.py is in the other folder project root.

Comment: then you should import using relative path to Classes, or add Classes to path to import

Comment: I got it, is was folder configuration, it was not as a package. Tks